# How to link my Meta user to standard Stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Is it possible to link my Meta user to my Stackoverflow.com user? If so, are there any advantages?

Comment: Why you want to link your account :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are already linked - check the Accounts tab of your profile on either site.

**Benefits of linking accounts**

If questions are migrated to Meta then you will still own them.

If you had more than 200 rep on one site then you'd get a 100 point bonus.

You can get this bonus when you hit 200 points by breaking and then remaking the association.

Meta Stack Overflow is special in that it has a separate rep from it's parent, but the same arguments apply for linking Stack Overflow, Super User, Web Apps, Gaming etc. accounts.

Comment: Actually, the Meta sub-site for StackOverflow is separate from StackOverflow whereas the Meta sub-sites for other StackExchange sites are linked to their main sites. For example, meta.superuser.com uses the same account as superuser.com, but meta.stackoverflow.com has a different account from stackoverflow.com. Obviously this is because when new sites were spawned, they eventually got their own Metas instead of sharing one, but StackOverflow still has an independent Meta.